# How can I select edge loops with Magic Mouse on a Mac?

Tags: modeling, workflow, osx

I’m on an iMac with a Magic Mouse (no scroll wheel or <kbd>RMB</kbd>). I use <kbd>RMB</kbd> selection, via <kbd>⌘ command</kbd> <kbd>LMB</kbd>. I have enabled Emulate 3 Button Mouse.

I'm trying to figure out how to select edge loops. The usual method is <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>LMB</kbd>, so for me that would be <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>LMB</kbd>, but that does nothing.

I tried adding this preference (and tried all the mouse action types: Any, Press, etc.), but still nothing.

[image]

How can I select edge loops with <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>LMB</kbd>?

Comment: Blender is designed to work with a mouse with left, right and a middle  (scroll) button . While it is possible to work around it it IMHO is a lot easier to get a cheap 3 button mouse and actually enjoy working on Blender the way it was desined to be used...

Comment: [here](http://superuser.com/questions/62762/how-to-enable-the-middle-button-of-apples-new-magic-mouse) are some little helpers for the magic mouse, but totally agree with @cegaton

Comment: @cegaton I tried using a 3-button mouse, but it's hard to use with my physical disability. Would be much easier from an a11y perspective if I could figure out how to compensate using Alt Command LMB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out! Whoo hoo. Turns out this is what I had to do:

[image]

1. Select an edge (using <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>LMB</kbd>)
2. Open the Select menu.
3. <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>LMB</kbd> (right-click) "Edge Loops".
4. Select "Add Shortcut".
5. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>LMB</kbd>, which Blender interprets as <kbd>Cmd</kbd> <kbd>Middle Mouse</kbd>.

It seems that <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>LMB</kbd> emulates the Middle Mouse Button. Not only that, `mesh.loop_multi_select` was the input I wanted, not `mesh.loop_select`, as I'd originally thought.

After I added that shortcut, this new input setting appeared in my user preferences:

[image]

All is not lost for Magic Mouse users.

Comment: can you tell me how did you configure your User Settings to have (Command LMB) instead of RMB. Just in case if you also know how to exchange MMB with something else would be a great Tip as well. I am starting with Blender and have a MacBook which I find super practical aside from the fact that I am starting to miss the middle and right button.

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same problem following this tutorial [Model & Rig Pistons fast in Blender 2.8+](https://youtu.be/e2a5mCa2Hj4?t=172). To select the edge loop it's said to use 'Shift alt click' but it doesn't work on my Mac. 
I made somme research on the internet and I arrived here but it doesn't help me.

After some tries, I figured that With Blender 2.8 when you have enabled Emulate 3 Button Mouse(Preferences > Input > activate Emulate 3 Button Mouse) **you just have to double click on the edge** to select the loop.

Hope this will help someone facing the same problem.

Comment: Hi, welcome. The question (4 years old) stated: "I have enabled Emulate 3 Button Mouse."...how is your late answer solving the issue or adding something useful? If it does, you could detail it a bit more...

Comment: @m.ardito clearly, the part in bold is the important part: once 3 button emulation is enabled, the short cut is not alt-click but just double-click. Who knows whether this was the answer 4 years ago, but it is now. It helped me.

Comment: OMG thank you so much I was so confused why control click stopped working. This help a lot

Comment: This answer worked great for me :)  Adding this comment since m.ardito's comment casts doubt on whether this answer works or not. (The other answers didn't work for me)