# I am using a Magic Mouse but am not able to select any vertices or faces

Tags: modeling

I am using a Magic Mouse but am not able to select any vertices or faces altought I have changed the use preference of the mouse to emulate 3 button mouse and select with right click in blender.
Can u help me with that.

Comment: Is [this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/35397/2217) that same as your question?

Answer (score 3):

I also work with a magic mouse and only changing the Blender user preference is not enough. You also have to change the right click settings in the system preferences of your apple system. So .. check Secondary Click for right click on the Mouse preferences.